# Store Multiple Dictionaries in list and iterate over the list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

okay so say I have a for loop that generates a dictionary how can I store the dictionary in a list and later iterate over the list and extract the dictionary I know this is kinda confusing so here is an example

```
for _ in 10:
    DB = {}
    DB["x"] = 1
    DB["y"] = 2
    DB["z"] = 3
    StoreDBInList(DB)
```

and then I can late do this

```
for DB in list:
    print(DB["x"])
    print(DB["y"])
    print(DB["z"])
```

Comment: Make `my_list = []` before the for loop and `my_list.append(DB)`...?

Comment: yes but how can I loop and extract the DB from the list later

Comment: After the first loop, you can just `for DB in my_list: print(DB["x"])` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the list outside the loop. Append to the list inside the loop. When iterating the list in a loop later, each element is a dict that you have created earlier.

```
lst = []
for i in range(3):
    dct = {'x': i, 'y': (i+1), 'z': (i+2)}
    lst.append(dct)

print(lst)
# [{'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 4}]

for dct in lst:
    print(dct['x'])
    print(dct['y'])
    print(dct['z'])
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok So @chris answered my question

Make my_list = [] before the for loop and my_list.append(DB)

After the first loop, you can just for DB in my_list: print(DB["x"]) and so on

Ex.

```
my_list = []

for _ in range(10):
    DB = {}
    DB["x"] = 1
    DB["y"] = 2
    DB["z"] = 3
    my_list.append(DB)

for DB in my_list:
    print(DB["x"])
    print(DB["y"])
    print(DB["z"])
```